# Some websites have abusive "debugger" statements which prevents inspecting and crashing

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints, web-inspector, chrome-debugging

Some websites have abusive "debugger" statements that prevent inspecting and crashing. Somehow they manage to prevent us using chrome developer tools. How to solve this?

I've tried:

"Never pause here" option. Which caused website to stop streaming.
"Deactivate breakpoints" option. Also caused stop streaming.
"Conditional breakpoint" and set false. Same thing happened.

How exactly they can detect us to activated Deactivate breakpoints option? I can give some website addresses but they are nsfw mostly.

Deactivate breakpoints option should work normally.

Comment: Can you add an example of such a website please?

Comment: @CherryDT for example javhdporn.net

Comment: You can use "devtools overrides" panel to edit these out.

Comment: @wOxxOm That's really interesting feature which I've never seen before. I will test it.